# multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identifier

I was trying this code to get the database related information.

the script is---

```
DECLARE @USER_Name SYSNAME
DECLARE @Database_Name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SQLQRY VARCHAR(2000)

DECLARE Database_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT '[' + NAME + ']' AS NAME
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE NAME IN ('Aaskiran')
ORDER BY NAME

OPEN Database_Cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM Database_Cursor
INTO @Database_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Database:' + @Database_Name

    EXECUTE (
            'SELECT Type, COUNT(*) As Objects FROM
    ' + @Database_Name + '.dbo.sysobjects
    GROUP BY Type ORDER BY Type'
            )

    EXECUTE (
            'SELECT name As Table_Name FROM
    ' + @Database_Name + '.dbo.sysobjects
     WHERE type=''U'' ORDER BY name'
            )

    EXECUTE (
            'SELECT name As Stored_Proc_Name FROM
    ' + @Database_Name + '.dbo.sysobjects
     WHERE type=''P'' ORDER BY name'
            )

    DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(255)

    EXECUTE (
            'DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name, USER_NAME(uid) FROM
    ' + @Database_Name + '.dbo.sysobjects
    WHERE type=''U'' ORDER BY name'
            )

    OPEN Table_Cursor

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Table_Cursor
    INTO @Table_Name,
        @User_Name

    SET @SQLQRY = 'SELECT 
                       SUM (row_count) 
                   FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
                   WHERE
                       object_id=OBJECT_ID(' + @Database_Name + '.[' + @User_Name + '].[' + @Table_Name + ']) 
                       AND (index_id=0  or index_id=1)'

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE (@SQLQRY)

        --EXECUTE('SELECT COUNT(*) AS ['+@Table_Name+'_Rows_Count] FROM '+@Database_Name+'.  ['+@User_Name+'].['+@Table_Name+']')
        --print('SELECT COUNT(*) AS ['+@Table_Name+'_Rows_Count] FROM '+@Database_Name+'.['+@User_Name+'].['+@Table_Name+']')
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM Table_Cursor
        INTO @Table_Name,
            @User_Name
    END

    CLOSE Table_Cursor

    DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Database_Cursor
    INTO @Database_Name
END

CLOSE Database_Cursor

DEALLOCATE Database_Cursor
```

but i am getting an error that

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "AasKiran.##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##.AADetails" could not be bound.

I have googled about this error but most of the links are on joins. I am not getting the issue in my query as i had also not used any alias or doing any sort of join.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is when you call `OBJECT_ID()` you are not wrapping the name of the table in quotes. You should use:

```
SET @SQLQRY = 'SELECT 
                   SUM (row_count) 
               FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
               WHERE
                   object_id=OBJECT_ID(''' + @Database_Name + '.[' + @User_Name + '].[' + @Table_Name + ']'') 
                   AND (index_id=0  or index_id=1)'
```

Although I'm still not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks steve; ya i got the bug. Well what i was trying to do is to make a count on the different entities of a database before and after an activity(certain tsql scripts run over it) has been carried out.
And the query is working now.
Thank you.